# GoogleMapの色をカスタマイズすると拡大した時に一部地域で色が元に戻る

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Wordpressのテーマで下記のものを使用しています。
地図の色がAPIを使用してカスタマイズされているのですが、日本の部分を拡大していくと、あるタイミングで韓国周辺で色がカスタマイズされていないデフォルトのものに変わってしまいます。
http://yourjourney.wiloke.net/map/

このテーマ独自の不具合でないことを確認するために、他のスタイルがカスタマイズされているGoogleMapを確認しましたが、すべてこのように色が変わっていました。

例えば下記のサイトのGoogleMapも同様にスタイルが変化します。
http://hayachi.github.io/modal_map/dark.html
→いずれかボタンをクリックして韓国近辺の地図を表示させてご確認ください

※この他、多数事例がありますがリンクが貼れないようなのでここまでにします

これはAPI側の問題で、どうしようもないことなのでしょうか？
それとも何か意図があってのことなのでしょうか？（他の地域でも色が変わっていないか探しましたが、今のところ韓国周辺のみです）。

Google Maps APIsのIssu trackerや英語版のstackoverflowなど確認しましたが、情報を見つけることができず、英語が得意でないため投稿するのは困難で、困っています。

原因や解決方法など、ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらぜひ教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googleが提供した[Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)というカスタマイズマップ生成器にも、このような現像が発生しています。

例：`Styled Maps Wizard`を利用して生成した福岡周辺の`Static Map`です。
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=33.576299,129.200592&zoom=8&format=png&sensor=false&size=640x640&maptype=roadmap&style=saturation:-50|gamma:2.00

でも、これは多分不具合。。。ではないです。丁寧に韓国だけがカスタマイズできないように設置した可能性が高いと思います。

一応[英語版](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568460/google-maps-style-does-not-apply-to-the-korea-area)にも投稿しとく。

=-=-=-= edit =-=-=-=

結論からいうと、カスタマイズすることは不可能です。

Googleの [Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2852) から見ると、韓国周辺でカスタマイズできない現像は既知の問題見たいです。残念ですが、今のところ解決策がないままなようです。

原因は韓国の法律と関係あると考えしております。こちらの　[Map Help Forum（韓国語）](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps-ko/AI_0FslsAs4)にもこのことを記載しています。 [(Naver Korean to Japanese translation)](http://translate.naver.com/#/ko/ja/%EC%98%88%2C%20%ED%95%9C%EA%B5%AD%EC%9D%80%20%EA%B5%AD%EB%82%B4%EB%B2%95%EC%83%81%20%EC%A7%80%EB%8F%84%20%EB%8D%B0%EC%9D%B4%ED%84%B0%EB%A5%BC%20%ED%95%B4%EC%99%B8%20%EB%8D%B0%EC%9D%B4%ED%84%B0%20%EC%84%BC%ED%84%B0%EB%A1%9C%20%EB%B0%98%EC%B6%9C%ED%95%A0%20%EC%88%98%20%EC%97%86%EB%8A%94%20%EC%A0%9C%EC%95%BD%EC%9D%B4%20%EC%9E%88%EC%96%B4%EC%84%9C%20%EA%B5%AC%EA%B8%80%20%EC%A7%80%EB%8F%84%EC%97%90%EC%84%9C%20%EC%A0%9C%EA%B3%B5%ED%95%98%EB%8A%94%20%EC%9D%BC%EB%B6%80%20%EA%B8%B0%EB%8A%A5%EC%9D%B4%20%EB%8F%99%EC%9E%91%ED%95%98%EC%A7%80%20%EC%95%8A%EB%8A%94%EB%8D%B0%2C%20%EC%97%AC%EA%B8%B0%EC%97%90%20%EC%A7%80%EB%8F%84%20%EC%9D%B4%EB%AF%B8%EC%A7%80%EB%A5%BC%20%EB%8F%99%EC%A0%81%EC%9C%BC%EB%A1%9C%20%EB%B3%80%EA%B2%BD%ED%95%98%EB%8A%94%20%EA%B8%B0%EB%8A%A5%EB%8F%84%20%ED%8F%AC%ED%95%A8%EB%90%A9%EB%8B%88%EB%8B%A4.%20%ED%95%9C%EA%B5%AD%20%EC%A7%80%EB%8F%84%EB%8A%94%20%EA%B5%AD%EB%82%B4%20%EC%84%9C%EB%B2%84%EB%A5%BC%20%ED%86%B5%ED%95%B4%20%EC%A0%9C%ED%95%9C%EC%A0%81%EC%9D%B8%20%EC%8A%A4%ED%83%80%EC%9D%BC%EC%9D%98%20%EC%A7%80%EB%8F%84%EB%A7%8C%20%EC%84%9C%EB%B9%84%EC%8A%A4%ED%95%98%EA%B3%A0%20%EC%9E%88%EA%B3%A0%2C%20%EA%B7%B8%20%EC%99%B8%20API%20%EB%93%B1%EC%9D%84%20%ED%86%B5%ED%95%9C%20%EC%A7%80%EB%8F%84%20%EC%9D%B4%EB%AF%B8%EC%A7%80%EC%9D%98%20%EB%B3%80%EA%B2%BD%EC%9D%80%20%ED%98%84%EC%9E%AC%EB%A1%9C%EC%84%9C%EB%8A%94%20%EC%96%B4%EB%A0%B5%EC%8A%B5%EB%8B%88%EB%8B%A4.%20%EC%B6%94%ED%9B%84%20%EB%B3%B4%EB%8B%A4%20%EB%A7%8E%EC%9D%80%20%EA%B5%AC%EA%B8%80%20%EC%A7%80%EB%8F%84%20%EC%84%9C%EB%B9%84%EC%8A%A4%20%EA%B8%B0%EB%8A%A5%EC%9D%84%20%EC%A7%80%EC%9B%90%ED%95%98%EA%B8%B0%20%EC%9C%84%ED%95%B4%20%EA%B3%84%EC%86%8D%20%EA%B0%9C%EC%84%A0%20%EC%9E%91%EC%97%85%EC%9D%84%20%EC%A7%84%ED%96%89%ED%95%98%EA%B3%A0%20%EC%9E%88%EC%8A%B5%EB%8B%88%EB%8B%A4%EB%A7%8C%2C%20%EC%A7%80%EA%B8%88%EC%9C%BC%EB%A1%9C%EC%84%9C%EB%8A%94%20%ED%95%B4%EB%8B%B9%20%EA%B8%B0%EB%8A%A5%EC%9D%B4%20%ED%95%9C%EA%B5%AD%EC%97%90%EC%84%9C%EB%8A%94%20%EC%A0%81%EC%9A%A9%EB%90%A0%20%EC%88%98%20%EC%97%86%EC%9D%8C%EC%9D%84%20%EC%96%91%ED%95%B4%ED%95%B4%20%EC%A3%BC%EC%8B%9C%EA%B8%B0%20%EB%B0%94%EB%9E%8D%EB%8B%88%EB%8B%A4.)

Comment: 英語版にも投稿していただいて本当にありがとうございます！
既知の問題だったんですね。法的な事情であれば諦めることとします。
大変助かりました、ありがとうございました。